# How do I add colour to this set of nodes?

Tags: node-editor

I'm attempting to create a sort of starry effect using nodes. However, I can't seem to be able to add colour to it. This is the following node setup:

[image]

And this is the result:

[image]

This is essentially three layers of noise textures. One on its own, and two modified with wave textures, to create different densities, and to add a cloudy effect. Unfortunately, this is all black and white, and I'd like to control the colour of each 'layer' of noise textures.

Changing the colours in any of the `ColorRamp` nodes has not helped. Setting random colours to any of these nodes simply controls brightness. Adding a `MixRGB` node before the `Math` nodes at any point seems to achieve the same result, or no change at all.

How can I add some colour to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace your *Math* nodes with *Vector Math* you can use a color ramp to color the result.

I'm not exactly sure what the end result should look like or why you chose the particular mathematical operations, so the end result is just to show that it contains color set by the color ramp.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure why I chose the mathematical nodes that way. It was a combination of looking at other online guides, and doing some experimentation on my part. Just playing around with different effects, I suppose. In any case, I'll give your suggestion a try in a little while.